# Decoding this simple JSON struct is not working

Tags: swift

I have a simple model which I defined to decode a struct.
But it is failing at decoding.
Can any one tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
struct Model: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int

    enum Codingkeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case age
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string: "https://learnappmaking.com/ex/users.json")!
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let d = try! decoder.decode([Model].self, from: data!) //fails here
            print(d)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I double checked to see if the json was correct, but it still fails to decode.

Error shown

> Thread 5: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
>   Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "firstName",
>   intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No
>   value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"firstName\",
>   intValue: nil) (\"firstName\").", underlyingError: nil))

It keeps searching for `firstName` but i specifically have a enum to check for `first_name`.

This is the JSON Payload

```
[
  {
    "first_name": "Ford",
    "last_name": "Prefect",
    "age": 5000
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Zaphod",
    "last_name": "Beeblebrox",
    "age": 999
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Arthur",
    "last_name": "Dent",
    "age": 42
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Trillian",
    "last_name": "Astra",
    "age": 1234
  }
]
```

I know I can add `decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase` but I want to know why the existing code is not working?

Comment: It is a simply typo: `Codingkeys` should be `CodingKeys`.

Comment: -___________-   all these hours.... @MartinR thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct, but apparently there is some problem with your model (although `convertFromSnakeCase` does work)

I retyped the struct and the error went away. Please copy and paste this

```
struct Model : Decodable {
    let firstName : String
    let lastName : String
    let age : Int

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case firstName  = "first_name", lastName  = "last_name", age }
}
```

Comment: it works!! is this a bug? Syntactically, there is no difference between your re-written model and mines right?

Comment: The code is not correct: The actual problem is a typo, see my above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the values are optional, to be safe make all let as optional, It will work for sure.

```
struct Model: Codable {
    let firstName: String?
    let lastName: String?
    let age: Int?

    enum Codingkeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case age
    }
}
```

Comment: This won’t fix the problem as there is a typo in the code. The enum should be `CodingKeys` not `Codingkeys`